# How to fix my bootstrap table layout issue?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hi I am having a layout issue. I am having an angular html form to perform some search and the results are displayed in a table using bootstrap 4 styles. However i am able to scroll the page so that a white portion is shown as in my screen shot. what should i do to avoid this .
[image]

the following is my html form .

```
<pc-header [heading]="'HEADINGS.MESSAGE_HISTORY_REPORTING' | translate" icon="history"></pc-header>

  <form novalidate [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit(formGroup.value)"> 

    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-3">
        <pc-form-field [required]="true" [errorMessages]="['required']">
          <pc-date-picker [range]="true" [minDate]="minStartDate" [maxDate]="maxEndDate" formControlName="range" [placeholder]="'PLACEHOLDERS.DATE_RANGE_PICKER' | translate"></pc-date-picker>
        </pc-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2">
          <select class="custom-select" formControlName="cdrStatus">
            <option [value]="" disabled>{{ 'LABELS.CDR_STATUS' | translate }}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let key of cdrStatusKeys" [value]="key"> {{ cdrStatuses[key] }} </option>
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2">
          <pc-form-field>
          <input formControlName="msisdn" type="text" placeholder="{{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.MSISDN' | translate }}" name="msisdn-name">
          </pc-form-field>
        </div>

      <div class="col-3">
          <select class="custom-select" *ngIf="isGlobalAdmin" formControlName="account">
              <option [value]="null" disabled>{{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.ACCOUNT_NAME' | translate }}</option>
              <option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [ngValue]="account"> {{ account.name }} </option>
            </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2 text-right">
          <pc-button theme="primary" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid" type="submit"> 
              {{ 'ACTIONS.RUN_REPORT' | translate }}
          </pc-button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <pc-form-field>
            <select formControlName="campaign">
                <option value="" disabled> {{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.SELECT_CAMPAIGNS' | translate }}  </option>
                <option *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns" [ngValue]="campaign">
                  {{ campaign.name }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </pc-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <pc-form-field>
            <select formControlName="inventory"> 
                <option value="null" disabled> {{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.SELECT_INVENTORIES' | translate }} </option>
                <option *ngFor="let inventory of inventories" [ngValue]="inventory">
                  {{ inventory.label }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </pc-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <pc-form-field>
            <select formControlName="flight">
                <option value="null" disabled> {{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.SELECT_FLIGHTS' | translate }} </option>
                <option *ngFor="let flight of flights" [ngValue]="flight"> {{ flight.name }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </pc-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-right">
            <pc-button theme="primary"  (click)="generateCSV(formGroup.value)" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">
                <i class="fas fa-download mr-2"></i>
                {{ 'ACTIONS.CSV' | translate }}
            </pc-button>
          </div>
    </div>

 </form> 

 <pc-spinner [standalone]="true" *ngIf="(isLoading && isInnerLoading) || executingElasticSearchQuery"></pc-spinner>

 <div class="table-wrap">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.TIME' | translate | uppercase}} </th>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.FROM' | translate | uppercase }} </th>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.TO' | translate | uppercase }} </th>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.CAMPAIGN' | translate | uppercase }} </th>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.FLIGHT' | translate | uppercase }} </th>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.STATUS' | translate  | uppercase}} </th>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.ERROR_CODE' | translate  | uppercase}} </th>
        <th scope="col"> {{ 'LABELS.MESSAGE_HISTORY.MESSAGE_TEXT' | translate  | uppercase }} </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of messageHistories | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: pageNumber, totalItems: totalHits }">
        <td> {{ item['@timestamp'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ item['sender'] }} </td>
        <td> {{ item['recipient'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ item['campaign_name'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ item['flight_name'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ item['status'] }}  </td>
        <td>{{ item['o_error'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ item['msg_text'] }}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>

     <div class="text-right" *ngIf="messageHistories">
      <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event, formGroup.value)" ></pagination-controls>
     </div>
     <div class="text-right text-muted" *ngIf="messageHistories">
        Found {{ totalHits }} records.
     </div>

  </div>
```

the following is my css file.

```
@import './../../../scss/mixins';
@import './../../../scss/variables';

label {
  @include pc-form-label;
}

.required::after {
  @include pc-required-asterisk;
}


.form-control {
    min-height: $min-form-input-height;
}

.search-form-background {
  background-color: $pc-search-bg-color;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.search-msisdn {
    background-color: $pc-search-bg-color;
    border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 18px;
  }
/*
  .table-responsive {
    height: 60%;
    margin-bottoms: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: auto;
    border-color: #ff0000;
  }
*/

.table-wrap {
  height: 700px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

how can change my styles so that I can display the page without the appearance of the white screen hightighted in the image.

thank you so much

Comment: Hard to tell from the code that you've shared already; if you can create a stackblitz which replicates this behavior, it'll be easier to help

Comment: Hi Akbar can i share the project in github. ? But inorder to run this project , you might need to install java 8 , maven , docker compose . ? the set up is bit complex . the code is here https://github.com/prasanthmp500/mep/tree/master/ui but please checkout the branch ENG-171

Comment: can you share a minimal code which replicates this issue, else it will take too long to setup and debug